# SCP not working for directory but works for a file - uploading from local to EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, scp

I'm trying to upload a folder from my local machine to an AWS EC2 instance. I've done this many times yet I'm currently having problems with SCP. I've tested SSH and SCP for files and they are working.

What am I missing? I've changed the permissions ( with: `sudo chmod -R 777 dir`  ) for both folder that I'm sending and the folder that is on the receiving end on the EC2.

I'm using Linux. The command that I have been using is the following:

`sudo scp -i -r /file_path/key.pem /file_path/dir_to_upload ec2-user@ec2_public_domain:/file_path/folder_to_receive_dir`

The error that I'm getting is the following:

`Warning: Identity file -r not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection`

I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: Voted to close - this is the wrong site for this

Comment: @daniel Hover your mouse over the "scp" tag and read the popup that appears. Another possibility is to ask on [unix.se].

Comment: Yes, wrong site.  In case you didn't read it: 'GENERAL SSH SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com' . This is on the `ssh` tag you used.

Answer (score 3):

Since this may help someone and I spent way too long on this issue.

The order of the -r and -i matter for this command.

`scp -i -r` does NOT work

The correct command is:

`scp -r -i /path/key.pem /path/dir_to_upload ec2-user@ec2_public_domain:/path/folder_to_receive_dir`

Also, to see what could be causing the error add a `-v` like so:

`scp -v -r -i /path/key.pem /path/dir_to_upload ec2-user@ec2_public_domain:/path/folder_to_receive_dir`